# Disable User Auto Timeout - Joomla 1.5

Tags: session, authentication, joomla, timeout

I wanted to disable user auto timeout session for joomla (I am using joomla 1.5), so the user login to my site will stay forever without being kicked out by auto timeout. How to achieve that? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Did the (1) answer answer your question? If so, please accept it as your answer, the solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's a setting in the login module. If you enable the "Remember Me" option, users will not be logged out unless they click the logout button. You can also modify the form so that the Remember Me option is a hidden field rather than a checkbox to default all users to stay logged in all the time.